# Why read-only permission account in Apache IoTDB received "no permission" when checking aligned data by device?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

In Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.2, when using the account with read-only permission to use `align by device` and the server prompted `no permission`. I checked and don't know how can I fix this problem while the account is already read-only permission. Also it seems like if I get rid of `align by device`, then the same account can query the results. Anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade Apache IoTDB version to 0.13.4, and the `read_timeseries` permission of the root path needs to be set.